# Powershell For Loop, Replace, Split, Regex Matches

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, split

```
$i=0;$pnp = pnputil -e;
$matched = [regex]::matches($pnp, ".......................................Lexmark International");
$split = $matched -split (".........inf");
$replace = $split -replace " Driver package provider :   Lexmark International","";
$replace1 = $replace -replace " ","`n";write-output $replace1;
foreach ($i in $replace1){;$pnpdel = pnputil -f -d $i;$pnpdel;};
Reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3\Lexmark Universal v2 XL" /f;
net stop spooler;net start spooler;start \\officechicprt5\111W-22E-CPRN-01
```

As you can hopefully see, my script tries to pull oem*.inf values from a pnpitil -e command.  I am trying to get each oem##.inf file to be it's own variable in a For loop.  My script is a bit of a mess with all the replaces and splits, but that part seems to get the part of the command that I need.  I am having issues with the data in $i.  It appears that the script will sometimes work, and sometimes not.  I want pnputil -d oem99.inf for each oem# it finds in the pnputil enumeration.  What am I doing wrong in my For loop?  There has to be a better way... I'm still pretty new to this as you can tell.

Thanks again.
Brent

Comment: "It appears that the script will sometimes work, and sometimes not." what happens when it appeard to not work?

Comment: The pnputil command would return an error, basically 'can't delete this'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leveraging the power in PowerShell we can turn the output of `pnputil` into an object array that will make it much easier to parse the data you are looking for (since it appears you are looking for something specific).

Each entry is a group of variables with a blank line in-between them. Using that lets turn this data into custom objects.

```psh
$rawdata = pnputil -e | Select-Object -Skip 1
$rawdata = $rawdata -join "`r`n" -split "`r`n`r`n"
$entries = $rawdata | ForEach-Object{
    $props = $_ -replace ":","=" | ConvertFrom-StringData
    new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
}
```

`$rawdata` initially contains the text from `pnputil -e`. We use `Select-Object -Skip 1` to remove the "Microsoft PnP Utility" line. Since `$rawdata` is an array this approach requires that is it one long string so `` -join "`r`n" ``. Immediately after we split it up into separate array elements of each property group with `` -split "`r`n`r`n" `` which splits on the blank line you see in cmd output.

The magic comes from `ConvertFrom-StringData` which create a hashtable from key value pairs in stings. In needs `=` to work so we convert the colons as such. With each hashtable that is created we convert it to an object and save it to the variable `$entries`. `$entries` will always be an array since it is safe to expect more than one entry.

Sample Entry once converted:

```
Class                   : Printers
Driver date and version : 12/03/2014 1.5.0.0
Signer name             : Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher
Published name          : oem27.inf
Driver package provider : Ricoh
```

Now we can use PowerShell to filter out *exactly* what you are looking for!

```psh
$entries | Where-Object{$_."Driver package provider" -match "Ricoh"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Published name"
```

Note that this can also return an array but for me there was only one entry. The output for this was `oem27.inf`

Then using the information you are actually looking for you can run your other commands.

Comment: Wow, that works great!  I wish I could vote this up.  Thank you so much

Comment: Some drivers may have a Signer name (or another value) with escape characters, which will make the script fail. You can add another `-replace "\\","\\\\"` to escape the escape characters using escaped escape characters :-)